# Как компилировать проект под разные платформы в различные файлы?

Tags: radstudio

Использую RAD Studio XE4. По-умолчанию проект компилируется в файл **projectname.exe**

Можно ли настроить компиляцию так, чтобы сборка под платформу Win32 происходила в один файл, например **projectname_32.exe**, а для Win64 в файл **projectname_64.exe**?

Просто нужны всегда обе версии, приходится компилировать одну, переименовывать, компилировать вторую и тоже переименовывать.